# Weird Umbraco issue - .Net User controls not in dropdown

Tags: umbraco

I have this strange problem - on a client install of umbraco, everything is working fine until I tried to add a .NET usercontrol to the usercontrol folder (and the dll to the bin). The usecontrol does not appear in the macro dropdown.  I have tried typing in the name of the usercontrol, /usercontrols/ProductsMenu.ascx, /ProductsMenu.ascx, umbraco/usercontrols/ProductsMenu.ascx

But I just keep geeing the following error:

```
User control doesn't exist
Please verify that you've copied the file to:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vhosts\mywebsite\ProductsMenu.ascx or
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vhosts\mywebsite\usercontrols\ProductsMenu.ascx or
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vhosts\mywebsite\umbraco\usercontrols\ProductsMenu.ascx
```

The XSLT and Scripting File macro work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't worry - I think its solved.

Comment: Why not share your resolution?...it may help someone else down the road.

Answer (score 0):

U have to create the usercontrols in umbraco admin interface in older versions. Afterwards u can overwrite the files if u need to in /usercontrols/ lib.